# How to load kuka iiwa R820 in ROS gazebo?

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I tried this code, it never worked..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not going to be able to call a launch file directly since it isn't an executable, just a markdown that `roslaunch` uses. Second, the reason it doesn't launch is because there is no built package called `iiwa_gazebo` in your workspace. You need to ensure the package is actually in `catkin_ws/src`. This means making sure the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` for the package are actually defining it as such.

As a side note, I noticed that your last question was about Ubuntu 20.04 and the only `iiwa_ros` package that exists targets Kinetic. This might not directly cause any errors, but it certainly isn't recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot, should I remove my current noetic ROS version and install the KInetic version?

Comment: No, because Kinetic is targeted at 16.04. If you want to use Kinetic you should use that. Otherwise you’re stuck on Noetic.